# I want to create an RSS feed that is customizable

Tags: rss

I want to create a dropdown of RSS feeds and users can pick and choose the feeds they want and a custom feed would be created. Is this possible using straight up HTML and java script or do I need a server technology.  There are 7 separate feeds so the possible combinations are 7! - far too many for me to individually code into if statements and separate feeds.  Is there a program that will generate the possible feeds for me automatically after I update one of them?  Then I could just upload the updated xml files.

---

Right.  So I set up my xml files, say I have one for birthdays, one for deaths, and one for mid life crises.  So that is three xml files with three separate links for rss feeds.  Now what I want is for people to be able to check off the ones to which they wish to subscribe rather than hitting each one separately.  So I would have a form with three checkboxes and a submit button.  I could do this with javascript by having 6 separate xml feeds, one for each possible combination.  But if I have 4 feeds then I need to set up 24 feeds, and 5 would be 120 possible feed combinations.

So the question becomes, is there some software or library that will either handle this computation for me and crank out RSS mixes/blends similar to what some RSS mixing software seems to do.  The problem with the services and software I have seen is that it provides blending for people subscribing to feeds but not for providers.  I can see in my head how easily this could be done programmatically even though it would spit out alot of xml and html/javascript.

I guess another way about it would be for them to sign up for multiple feeds simultaneously but I'm not sure if that can be done.

If I am making no sense I apologize.  I have never seen this done so it might not be possible.  I am just going to go with the page with a bunch of RSS links.

Thanks for everyones responses.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Just because there are 7 options doesn't mean you need to write 7! if statements. You only need to check if each one of the options is set, and output something appropriately.

So, yes, you need to do this server side. And it's not at all difficult.

Where are you stuck, specifically? Your question is missing a few details.

Comment: I am working in a vanilla html environment.  Just javascript and css here, no php, cf, .net, etc..  So whatever solution fits best will need to be either javascript or html heavy.  I'm begining to think a page with just a list of RSS feeds is the easiest solution.